# Странное поведение OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, windows-7, radeon, opentk

С использованием библиотеки OpenTK пытаюсь равномерно заполнить поле точками, но почему-то столь простая вещь не получается.
При определенных значениях появляются полосы - незаполненные участки.
Лучше всего это можно видеть на скриншоте:

[image]

Привожу полный код:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Input;

namespace testOpenTK
{
    class Game : GameWindow
    {
        public Game()
            : base(900, 900, GraphicsMode.Default, "OpenTK Quick Start Sample")
        {
            VSync = VSyncMode.On;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            GL.ClearColor(Color.White);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
            GL.LoadIdentity();
            GL.Ortho(0, Width, 0, Height, -1, 1); // Верхний левый угол имеет кооординаты(0, 0)
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height); // Использовать всю поверхность GLControl под рисование

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when it is time to setup the next frame. Add you game logic here.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Contains timing information for framerate independent logic.</param>
        protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnUpdateFrame(e);

            if (Keyboard[Key.Escape])
                Exit();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when it is time to render the next frame. Add your rendering code here.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Contains timing information.</param>
        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);

            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.LoadIdentity();

            GL.PointSize(1);

            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Points);


            for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
                {
                    GL.Color3(Color.Violet); GL.Vertex2(i, j);
                }
            }
            GL.End();
            SwapBuffers();
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (Game game = new Game())
            {
                game.Run(30.0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Может, кто-нибудь знает, что может быть источником проблемы?

Версия opentk-1.1/stable-5.
ОС Windows 7.
Видеокарта ATI Radeon HD 5700

Answer (score 1):

У вас нету ошибок в коде. Карты от ATI Radeon не слишком хорошо дружат с OpenGL, по этому вероятно проблема в драйверах видеокарты.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо отрисовки точек отрисовывать залитые прямоугольники размером в один пиксель (или чуть меньше).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.